# Using Visual Studio "Watch" with ref class references

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-phone-8, c++-cx

I am trying to debug a Windows Phone 8 native app using VS2012.

I've hooked up an event handler to the *PointerPressed* event.

When trying to view the *args* that are passed to the handler function, i cannot see any of the members in the editor as a tooltip, or in the Watch window:

[image]

Is there any way to view these arguments? and in genreal, is this an issue with ref class type arguments?

Comment: All of its members are properties, and to view the value of a property, a function must be called (the property accessor).  The native debugger should never attempt to call functions automatically.  It should be possible to call the accessor directly, though, e.g. by adding as a watch `args->get_CurrentPoint()`.  That doesn't seem to work, though; if no one finds a solution this weekend I can chat up the debugger folks on Monday and see what the recommended solution is.

Comment: That'd be great. Coming from C#, it seems obvious i could peek into any variable to look at it's members, or at least evaluate its methods in the Watch/Immediate window.

Comment: Is there any word from the kind debugger folks?